# How to apply error correction.and detection On raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, linux

I want to send data from rs232 to raspberry pi and I want to know if we can achieve error correction and detection on raspberry pi

Comment: Yes you can.  As a matter of interest which error correction and detection methods are you planning to use?  Voting to close as not Pi specific.

Comment: I want to use forward error correction I'm asking about how to apply

Comment: I do not understand the problem.  Add the FEC as part of the transmitted bytes and strip/use the FEC from the received bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this new thing called ["Google"](https://www.google.com/) is an amazing tool  :)

Reed-Solomon and convolutional codes do FEC. [Reed-Solomon is actually part of the Linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/core-api/librs.html) in some distros, but unfortunately, it seems to have been deleted from Raspbian. However, there are numerous libraries with source code on GitHub. What I don't know is how much (if any) extra effort is required to get these libraries to compile for Raspbian's ARM processor:

- A C-language library called [libcorrect](https://github.com/quiet/libcorrect) is available that offers both Reed-Solomon and convolutional codes
- [schifra](https://github.com/ArashPartow/schifra) is a C++ Reed Solomon Error Correcting Library
- If you prefer a [Python implementation](https://github.com/tomerfiliba/reedsolomon) of Reed-Solomon
- Others include: [fecmagic (C++)](https://github.com/Venemo/fecmagic), and a [Reed-Solomon that uses BCH (Bose–Chaudhuri–Hocquenghem) codes](https://github.com/mersinvald/Reed-Solomon)
- And for some useful background, check out this [wikiversity article on Reed-Solomon useful for coders](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_codes_for_coders)

Hope that helps get you started. We'll look forward to hearing how you get on with this. Please issue follow-up posts if you need help with any details.